# add more participants to existing events programatically

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible to "forward" existing events to other participants programatically?

Let's say there is event with PersonA + PersonB, and my app suggest to add PersonC - can the app add person C to the event list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's possible using [Events.update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update). That's because in the request body, the

```
"attendees": [
    {
      "email": "addedguest@gmail.com"
    }]
```

is still present.